# getting "ImportError" when trying to run the scrapy from the script

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm writting a scrapy spider to crawl the hackernews website to get the title and publisher text and store them in a **.csv file**.I want to be able to run it from the script itself not from the shell, for that I'm using `CrawlerProcess` so I could run it from the script, when I use `from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess` **VScode** doesn't show me any error and I use

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  process = CrawlerProcess()
  process.crawl(Hackernews_crawler)
  process.start()
```

in the end of the script (I found it on medium ) vscode doesn't show me any error either, but when I run the script it give's me

```
  File "/home/amirmhd/Desktop/crawler/web_crawler_bot/web_crawler_bot/spiders/hacker_news_crawler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..items import Hackernews_items
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I couldn't figure it out why running it as the script gives me this error but when I run it in the shell with `scrapy crawl hackernews` it works fine!
[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKJqr.png)

I don't know what is wrong with items importing that it gives an error running as script but it doesn't in the shell [this is my webcrawler directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Mid.png).
I cant understand where the error actully come from, is it because of the `CrawlerProcess` or because of `from ..items import Hackernews_items`!

Im using venv and i installed scrapy with `pip3 install scrapy`, OS ubuntu 20.04 LTS

appreciate in advance for your time

Comment: How do you start your script ? It could be a cwd issue

Comment: @G.Vernier for shell command I'll go to the spider folder and then run the "scrapy crawl hackernews" and for running it as a script I just use "ctrl+F5" in VScode. Is there a issue with my approach?

Comment: what is the root of your VSC workspace ? the current working dir of the python app might not be the same, thus not having the same import root

Comment: @G.Vernier i checked it out, their in the same workspace